# On Text Entered Change Textbox border color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `checkbox`, when `checkbox` is *checked* the near by `textbox` *border color* should change into green if it is *unchecked* the `textbox` *border color* should be in red. 
Jquery code:

```
$('#item_availability1_unlimited').on('change', function () {

    if ($('#item_availability1_unlimited').is(':checked')) {
        $('#item_availability1').css('border', '2px solid #11b818');
    } else {
        $('#item_availability1').css('border', '2px solid #F00');
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zain0788/tLsXq/)

I have done the above part what i need is the below:

And also if the `textbox` is empty then its *border color* should be red, if it is entered with text it should change into green.

Comment: You can replace, $('#item_availability1_unlimited').is(':checked') with this.checked

Comment: f the text box is empty then its border color should be red, if it is entered with text it should change into green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle.

Choose `jQuery` from the `Frameworks and Extensions` tab and it should work.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLsXq/3/)**

---

Edit: Based on your comment, you need to use:

```
$('#item_availability1_unlimited').on('change', function () {

    if ($('#item_availability1_unlimited').is(':checked')) {
        $('#item_availability1').css('border', '2px solid #11b818');
    } else {
        $('#item_availability1').css('border', '2px solid #F00');
    }
}).change();

$('#item_availability1').on('keyup', function () {
 if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $('#item_availability1').css('border', '2px solid #11b818');
    } else {
        $('#item_availability1').css('border', '2px solid #F00');
    }
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLsXq/4/)**

Comment: what i need is this "if the text box is empty then its border color should be red, if it is entered with text it should change into green."